# How to write Linq left join with multiple fields where one is case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, linq-to-objects

What is preferred way to convert this to a Left Join?  This is Linq to Objects (not SQL).

```
var result = 
(
   from e in entries
   from r in results
   where r.PropertyId == e.PropertyId &&
         e.ValueAsString.Equals(r.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
   select new
   {
      Result = r,
      Entry = e
  }
)
.ToList();
```

Issues:  Tradeoff between readability vs. efficiency.  Should try to avoid ToLowerInvariant()?

Comment: what you write is cross join, not left join

Comment: Not entirely sure if you need help with the query itself or only with comparing the strings, but to find what is better performance-wise you can just run tests `"abc".Equals("AbC", StringComparison.InvCultIC)` vs `"abc".Equals("AbC".ToLowerInv())`. You can also go crazier with the test cases, of course.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there can only be 0 or 1 results matching each entry.

Comment: I knew it was a cross but I didn't know that the "join" keyword would create an internal Lookup to to avoid the cross comparisons (from user @Servy).  Thanks.  This happens to be for very small sets.

Answer (score 0):

what you write is `cross join`, not `left join`

```
var result = 
(
   from e in entries
   join r in results
   let ev=e.ValueAsString.ToLower()
   let rv=r.Value.ToLower()
   on new{e.PropertyId,ev} equals new {r.PropertyId,rv } into lg
   from r in lg.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new
   {
      Result = r,
      Entry = e
  }
)
.ToList();
```

Comment: I'm confused by this, but will only comment on what I know: `r==null?null:r` is just `r`.

Answer (score 0):

For left joins you need to use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var result = 
    (
       from e in entries
       from r in results.Where(x => x.PropertyId == e.PropertyId)
                        .Where(x => e.ValueAsString.Equals(x.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new
       {
          Result = r,
          Entry = e
      }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Looks like this would get the right answer but still execute as nested linear searches.  Applicable to small sets only.  I was told by @Servy that using the "join" keyword will add an internal Lookup table during execution so leaning that way for a general purpose answer.