# How to write left-join with a case in Linq (C# MVC)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, left-join

How do I write the following query in Linq:

```
SELECT s.displayname AS Skill, 
       CASE 
         WHEN us.skillid IS NULL THEN '0' 
         ELSE '1' 
       END           AS HasSkill 
FROM   skills s 
       LEFT JOIN userskills us 
              ON s.id = us.skillid
```

I've been at it for a couple of hours and I genuinely cannot get my head around the structure of these queries. They seem overwhelming and too complicated for what the plain SQL query otherwise seems to be doing for me.

```
var skills = _context.Skills.ToList();
var userSkills = _context.UserSkills.ToList();

var result = skills.GroupJoin(userSkill, skill => skill.ID, skill => userSkill , (userSkill, skill) => new {
                Key = userSkill,
                Skills = skill
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936028/linq-case-statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254939/how-to-write-linq-left-join-with-multiple-fields-where-one-is-case-insensitive

Comment: For left joins you need to use DefaultIfEmpty                                                                                   d `var result = 
    (
       from e in entries
       from r in results.Where(x => x.PropertyId == e.PropertyId)
                        .Where(x => e.ValueAsString.Equals(x.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new
       {
          Result = r,
          Entry = e
      }
    )
    .ToList();`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have already seen those questions. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: if you add a navigation property, you can use method syntax and use .Include(), which will automatically translate into a left outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `linq` with `DefaultIfEmpty()` make `LEFT JOIN`

then use `select` with the ternary operator to make `CASE WHEN`

```
from s in skills
join u in userSkills 
on new s.id equals u.skillid 
into temp
from u in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { 
    Skill=s.displayname,
    HasSkill= us.skillid == NULL ? "0" : "1"
}
```

Comment: Is that `DefaultIfEmpty()` what 'turns it into' a LEFT join rather than an inner join?

Comment: Hang on, what's `us` - is that from line 2? That's supposed to be "join us" I'm guessing.